# How to configure Nginx for a Laravel website to use SSL with Let's Encrypt on Ubuntu Focal server with php8.0?

Tags: laravel, nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt

I'm currently using the default configuration below, provided by Laravel [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /srv/www/example/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

What configuration should I use instead to switch to SSL with **Let's Encrypt** ?

With this current configuration, when I run `certbot`, I'm getting the error below:

```
~  sudo certbot --nginx -d www.example.com
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator nginx, Installer nginx
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for www.example.com
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain www.example.com
http-01 challenge for www.example.com
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: www.example.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/KLiVD9nJaMVqJoljNziftqSJXFXCEXsV5mf_d9WthdM
   [123.123.123.3]: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML
   2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>404 Not
   Found</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<p"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

When scanning ports from outside my network, I get:

```
$ nmap 123.123.123.3
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-12-14 11:13 CET
Nmap scan report for 213.163.173.3
Host is up (0.0061s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp  open   http
113/tcp closed ident
443/tcp open   https
```

Comment: just enter `sudo certbot` it will give u all the available domain name

Comment: @KamleshPaul After choosing my domain in the list, I'm still getting the same error message

Comment: then `please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.`

Comment: The website works fine without SSL, I guess it's enough to say that the domain name and ip are set correctly

Comment: no it you need to check AAAA record as well you need to cross check both

Comment: Okay, thanks, indeed I might not have AAAA record set, is it mandatory to use Let's Encrypt ?

Comment: no it is not mandatory but  if you have other ip in A or AAAA record then let's encrypt not work so remove those if not req.

Comment: When I do `dig A +short www.example.com`, I get `proxy-1.example.com.` and `123.123.123.3`, then when I do `dig AAAA +short www.example.com`, I just get `proxy-1.example.com.`, does it confirm that my problem comes from incorrect AAAA record ? Knowing that `proxy-1.example.com` points to `123.123.123.3`

Comment: why don't you check your dns manager everything will be clear from there

Comment: I don't have access to this DNS for the moment, so I'm trying alternative ways to check whether it's actually the problem or not